# How to update upvote counter for individual elements instead of all of them at once with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

Newbie dev learning React.

I'm trying to create an upvote functionality to a blog post in React but when I click on the upvote button I'm upvoting all of the blog post cards at once instead of the individual card.

How can I fix this? I believe the issue may be in the way I'm setting setState? But I may be wrong and looking for help.

Thanks in advance!

====

```
class Posts extends Component {

    state= {
        points: 0
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts()
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.newPost) {
          this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
        }
      }


    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({points: this.state.points + 1})
    }

    render() {

        const postItems = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (

            <div key={index} className="ui three stackable cards">
                <div className="ui card">
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="header">{post.title}</div>
                        <div className="meta"> {post.author}</div>
                        <div className="description">
                        <p>{post.body}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="extra content">
                        <i className="check icon"></i>
                        {this.state.points} Votes
                    </div>
                    <button className="ui button" 
                        type="submit" 
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>Add Point</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        ))

        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <h2 className="ui header">
                    <i className="pencil alternate icon"></i>
                <div className="content">
                    Blog Feed
                    <div className="sub header"><a href="/posts/new">Create New Post!</a></div>
                </div>
                </h2>
                {postItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your posts have unique identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are upvoting every card because you have only one counter. A separate counter should be defined for every card.

```
state = {}; // dictionary-a-like state structure

handleClick = (id) => () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ 
       [id]: prevState[id] ? prevState[id] + 1 : 1, // check and increment counter
    }));
}

onClick={this.handleClick(post.id)} // call function with post.id as argument

{this.state[post.id] || 0} Votes // display votes for every card
```

**Note**: I assumed that every card has it's own unique id, if not - `index` may come handy too.

Comment: Very cool, I learned from your code and from Nick's above you. QQ tho, why is it better or what are the benefits of setting state as an empty object rather integer 0?

Comment: @RafaelLopez Integer 0 has no sense since it would be static for every card. You need a flexible solution so every separate card has its own counter :) Object fits nicely for those cases, just like yours one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single component storing the "points" state for all your posts. To achieve the functionality you described, each post should be it's own component with it's own state.

```
class Post extends Component {

    state = {
        points: 0
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({points: this.state.points + 1})
    }

    render = () =>
        <div key={index} className="ui three stackable cards">
                <div className="ui card">
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="header">{this.props.title}</div>
                        <div className="meta"> {this.props.author}</div>
                        <div className="description">
                        <p>{this.props.body}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="extra content">
                        <i className="check icon"></i>
                        {this.state.points} Votes
                    </div>
                    <button className="ui button" 
                        type="submit" 
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>Add Point</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need one counter for each post. Currently you only have a single counter for all posts, which means that they all display that same value.

The best way to achieve this would probably be to separate your post into its own component, and have that keep track of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses a post ID (if you have it) to create a key in a stateful `points` object. Then, on click, you can add to the correct points key.

```
state = {
  points: {}
}

handleClick = postId => {
  this.setState({ 
    points: {
      ...this.state.points,
      [postId]: (this.state.points[postId] || 0) + 1
    }
  })
}

const postItems = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (
  ...
  <div className="extra content">
    <i className="check icon"></i>
    {this.state.points[post.id] || 0} Votes
  </div>
  <button 
    className="ui button" 
    type="submit" 
    onClick={() => this.handleClick(post.id)}
  >
    Add Point
  </button>
  ...
)
```